# ViewPager with adapter " " requires a view id In AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask in which I create a ViewPager and when I assign an adapter to it, this error appears

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager with adapter com.example.kos.PagerAdapterZvon@646addd requires a view id
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.startUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:83)
>           at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1124)
>           at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
>           at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
>           at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:726)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6834)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:847)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23466)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2954)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2041)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1636)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7946)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1092)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:893)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:812)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1078)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

**AsyncTask**

```
     class StartAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String[],Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
            linearLayout.addView(progressBar, layoutParams);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsKek = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParamsKek.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
           ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(context);
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            linearLayout.addView(viewPager,layoutParamsKek);
//            Date start = new Date();
//            switch (start.toString().substring(0,3)) {
//                case "Mon":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
//                    url = "Monday.txt";
//                    break;
//                case "Tue":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
//                    url = "Tuesday.txt";
//                    break;
//                case "Wed":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
//                    url = "Wednesday.txt";
//                    break;
//                case "Thu":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
//                    url = "Thursday.txt";
//                    break;
//                case "Fri":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
//                    url = "Friday.txt";
//                    break;
//                case "Sat":
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
//                    url = "Saturday.txt";
//                    break;
//                default:
//                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
//                    url = "Monday.txt";
//                    break;
//            }
////            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
////            editor.putString("Day", url);
////            editor.apply();
////            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
////            tabLayout.setScrollX(tabLayout.getWidth());
////            tabLayout.getTabAt(5).select();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapterZvon(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
class PagerAdapterZvon extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private String[] name;
        PagerAdapterZvon(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            name = new String[] {
                    "Понедельник",
                    "Вторник",
                    "Среда",
                    "Четверг",
                    "Пятница",
                    "Суббота"

            };
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            return name[position];
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 6;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new classMonday();
                case 1:
                    return new classTuesday();
                case 2:
                    return new classWednesday();
                case 3:
                    return new classThursday();
                case 4:
                    return new classFriday();
                case 5:
                    return new classSaturday();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

All action occurs in a fragment, and if to remove AsyncTask and to transfer all actions to onCreate that everything works

Answer (score 1):

Just call setId(R.id.your_id);

```
viewPager.setId(R.id.viewPagerId);
```

You can create a R.id id by pressing OPTION + ENTER (on the error, that exists because of the unresolved id) and click Create new id value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating your Viewpager totally from code and not via layout file which is why you are getting that error (requires a view id) . Please follow the instructions here when creating viewpager:

[ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: Yes I create a ViewPager in code just like I did in another AsyncTask but with a different adapter and everything worked

Comment: Any specific reason why you'd follow that approach? By right, ViewPager is a UI item and should be created via layout file as per the link I shared. Creating UI items from code has lot of handling especially if you are doing in AsyncTask because it runs on another thread.

Comment: add an Id to your layout. Define an Id in resources folder and set that id to your layout, It may fix your problem